# How can I work around the same-origin policy to develop AJAX client code for a Google AppEngine site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers, same-origin-policy

I'm working with someone who has a Google AppEngine site with a custom API located there.

I need to write some AJAX Javascript to interface with the custom API on the site, but I'm getting stonewalled by the same-origin policy. JSONP will be of no use because you can't get an error callback from a failed 'AJAX' request (it doesn't use XMLHTTPRequest). I am using JQuery to make the requests.

Apparently Google AppEngine has a terrible caveat that you can't individually upload single files for testing, so I can't fix this problem by developing directly on the API's proper domain.

I'm on a MAC and I have heard you can set up some kind of proxy to get around this, I have no idea even where to start with that, and don't want to if I don't absolutely have to. What can I do to allow me to develop some AJAX JS against this API?

Comment: Can you get the data you need by making your request from your _server-side_ code? That is, an ajax request from browser to your web server (same domain), and then your web server gets the data from the other domain and returns it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by nerfing the same-origin policy support in my browser (Chrome) such that it no longer functions or is honored. During development, I can make cross-domain requests and the browser will not act to prevent them. If you run into this problem like I did, launch Chrome like this:

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security

This is obviously a development-only solution, but thats all I needed. For more extensive solutions the above answers concerning CORS and JSONP + properly designed JSONP APIs are more appropriate.

Comment: I like this method, because it only lasts as long as Chrome runs, so you can quit and test with normal security. And have the security on while browsing the web.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just looking for a development-time solution (i.e. setting up a proxy) I would recommend Charles Web Proxy (http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

It's what I use for my local development - it can intercept requests to URLs and redirect them to other locations to get around cross-domain issues (for local development and testing - not production of course). It's pretty easy to get setup and working, and there is a free trial available.

Comment: This is a good recommendation, and one of the ways to solve this problem. Another is disabling the security in the browser such that it no longer honors the same-origin policy. This is the route I ended up taking, but thank you for this answer!

Comment: Another advantage of this approach is that it allows for testing your site from various browsers without trying to configure each browser to avoid the same-origin policy.

Comment: @Sly_cardinal I'm unable to see OPTIONS requests in Charles. Anything else that needs to be configured? :/

Answer (score 1):

Generally, JSONP APIs do not fail to respond, for that reason among others.  Even if something goes wrong, well-designed ones respond with something like:

```
response({
   error: {...}
});
```

or similar.  Thus, you should always get a response unless there's a network connectivity issue or the server has a serious failure (e.g. App Engine goes down).  If the API does not return valid JSON for errors, I would suggest changing that.

Comment: You mean, you should always get a response unless there's the kind of problem there usually is?  :-P

Comment: @Malvolio, I know you're being tongue in cheek, but these kinds of errors are relatively rare, compared to the many others (bad user id, invalid method name, can't connect to the database, not authenticated, and too many more to list)

Comment: I'm being *kind* of tongue-in-cheek, but if I agreed that system-level (rather than application-level) error were particularly rare, I wouldn't have brought it up.  Today, we did a big site release.  Lots of errors.  At least half of them were outside the applications ability to control the messaging.   Just not a big JSONP fan and error-handling is just one of the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).  Your friend's site has to permit CORS and if you want your code to support IE (it sounds like you don't) you have to use a special plugin like [this one](https://gist.github.com/1114981).